# How to show the inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $r \in \left(0,1\right),\ \phi \in \left(0,2\pi\right)$.
$$
\mbox{For}\quad
\vec{x} = \left(\vphantom{\large A}
r_{1}\cos\left(\phi_{1}\right),
r_{1}\sin\left(\phi_{1}\right)\right),\quad
\vec{y} = \left(\vphantom{\large A}
r_{2}\cos\left(\phi_{2}\right),
r_{2}\sin\left(\phi_{2}\right)\right)
$$
it holds
$\displaystyle\left\vert\,{\vec{x} - \vec{y}}\,\right\vert \geq
\left\vert\,{r_{1} - r_{2}}\,\right\vert$.

Has anyone got  an idea ?. Thank you .

Comment: [MSE-$\texttt{MathJax}$-$\LaTeX$ Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to show
$$\begin{split}
|x-y|&\geq ||x|-|y|| \\ 
\Leftrightarrow (x-y)(x-y)&\geq ||x|-|y||^2 \\
&=(|x|-|y|)^2 \\
&=|x|^2-2|x||y|+|y|^2.
\end{split}$$
But the left hand side is 
$$x\cdot x-2xy+y\cdot y=|x|^2-2xy+|y|^2$$
and it remains to show that
$$-2xy\geq -2|x||y|\Leftrightarrow |x||y|\geq xy,$$
which is just the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: is there also a geometric meaning behind this ?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the length of the segment $\overline{XY}$ is greater than the difference of the distances of $X$ and $Y$ to the origin.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

To show $|A|\le B$, you only have to show successively that $A\le B$ and  $-A\le B$.

Write $\vec x=(\vec x-\vec y)+\vec y$ and use the triangle inequality to show  $|\vec x|-|\vec y|\le |\vec x-\vec y|$.

Can you see why this also proves $|\vec y|-|\vec x|\le|\vec x-\vec y|\,$?

Comment: is there also a geometric meaning behind this ?

Comment: Oh! yes. It's from medschool: In a triangle, the length of a side is between the sum and the difference of the lengths of the two other sides.